# BFS for graphs using link list, c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, breadth-first-search

I tried to implement BFS for graphs using link list but i have some issues with it, using a queue it only displays the nodes of that origin and not after it. The answer should be 2031 but i only get 203.

The code is below:

```
            #include <iostream>
            #include <cmath>
            #include <vector>
            #include <stdlib.h>
            #include <queue>

            using namespace std;

            class linkListNode
            {
            public:
                linkListNode *next;
                int destination;
                bool visited;

                linkListNode()
                {
                    next = NULL;
                    destination =0;
                    visited=false;
                }
            };

            class linkList
            {
            public:
                linkListNode *head;

                linkList()
                {
                    head = NULL;
                }

                // append type insert
                void insert(int value)
                {
                    linkListNode *temp2 = new linkListNode;
                    temp2->destination = value;
                    temp2->next = NULL;
                    linkListNode *nodePtr = new linkListNode;

                    if (head == NULL)
                    {
                        head = temp2;
                        temp2->next = NULL;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        nodePtr = head;
                        while (nodePtr->next)
                        {
                            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
                        }
                        nodePtr->next = temp2;
                    }
                }

                void display()
                {
                    linkListNode *temp = new linkListNode;
                    temp = head;

                    while (temp)
                    {
                        cout << temp->destination << " --> ";
                        temp = temp->next;
                    }
                    cout << endl;
                }


                int size()
                {
                    linkListNode *temp = head;
                    int sizer = 0;
                    while (temp)
                    {
                        sizer++;
                        temp = temp->next;
                    }
                    return sizer;
                }
            };

            class edge
            {
            public:
                int origin;
                linkList final;
                bool visited;

                edge()
                {
                    //origin = NULL;
                    //cost=0;
                    visited=false;
                }
            };

            class  graph
            {  
            private:
                vector <edge> vectorOfEdges;
                int vertices;

            public:
                graph(int v)
                {
                    vertices = v;
                    vectorOfEdges.clear();
                }

                void addRoute(int ori, int dest)
                {
                    int counter = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i<vectorOfEdges.size(); i++)
                    {
                        edge e = vectorOfEdges[i];
                        if (e.origin== ori)
                        {
                            counter = 1; // means element was present in the list
                            e.final.insert(dest);
                        }
                        vectorOfEdges[i] = e;
                    }

                    if (counter == 0) // when counter is set to zero, this means that the element was not found in the vector and needs to be pushed
                    {
                        edge e;
                        e.origin = ori;
                        e.final.insert(dest);
                        vectorOfEdges.push_back(e);
                    }
                }

                void printGraph()
                {
                    edge e;
                    for (int i = 0; i<vectorOfEdges.size(); i++)
                    {
                        e = vectorOfEdges[i];
                        cout << e.origin << ":- ";
                        e.final.display();
                        cout << endl;
                    }
                }

                int sizeOfEdge(edge e)
                {
                    int x = e.final.size() + 1;
                    return x;
                }

                int max(int one, int two)
                {
                    if (one > two)
                    {
                        return one;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        return two;
                    }
                }

                void BFS(int start)
                {
                    edge e;
                    queue <int> q;
                    int save_index=0;
                    for (int i=0;i<vectorOfEdges.size();i++)
                    {
                        e=vectorOfEdges[i];
                        if (e.origin == start)
                        {
                            save_index=i;
                            q.push(e.origin);
                            e.visited=true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    while (!q.empty())
                    {
                        int x=q.front();
                        cout << x << " " ;
                        q.pop();

                        linkListNode *l = e.final.head;
                        while (l)
                        {
                            if (l->visited == false)
                            {
                                q.push(l->destination);
                                l->visited=true;
                                l=l->next;
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                l=l->next;
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                }

            };

            int main()
            {
                graph g(4);
                g.addRoute(0, 1);
                g.addRoute(0, 2);
                g.addRoute(1, 2);
                g.addRoute(2, 0);
                g.addRoute(2, 3);
             // g.printGraph();
                //cout << "Following is Breadth First Traversal (starting from vertex 2) \n";
                g.BFS(1);
            }
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Any reason why you're not simply using `std::list` or `std::forward_list`?  You're using `vector` and `queue`, so why not `std::list`?

Comment: i actually added cost and some other functionalities in the code which i later on edited, thats why. Any idea what the problem is though? @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @NathanOliver i do know how to use one but idk what the problem is for this code ...

Comment: @SaimMahmood - *i actually added cost and some other functionalities in the code which i later on edited, thats why* -- That is not a good reason.  A `std::list` will add and remove nodes without you having to write code to do this.  I take it that you never knew `std::list` existed, else you wouldn't go through this torture of trying to write your own.

Comment: @SaimMahmood Your `edge` class does not initialize all of the members when constructed.  Your `origin` is uninitialized.  Also, your code does not produce the output you say it does.  [See this](http://ideone.com/rTeM88).  Also, [see this](http://ideone.com/e0qYWw) using `std::list` .  It is much shorter, and note the output (except for the extra carriage return) is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only running for the node that you have provided as the starting value for your BFS traversal.

```
void BFS(int start)
{

    queue<int> q;
    bool startFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorOfEdges.size(); i++)
    {
        edge e = vectorOfEdges[i];
        if (e.origin == start)
        {
            q.push(e.origin);
            check.push_back(e.origin);
            e.visited = true;
            startFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!startFound)
    {
        cout << "Start vertex not found in the graph" << endl;
        return;
    }

    while (!q.empty())
    {

        int x = q.front();
        cout << x << " ";
        q.pop();

        for (int i = 0; i < vectorOfEdges.size(); i++)
        {
            edge e = vectorOfEdges[i];
            if (e.origin == x)
            {
                linkListNode *l = e.final.head;

                while (l != NULL)
                {
                    bool found = false;
                    if (l->visited == false)
                    {
                        l->visited = true;
                        for (int i = 0; i < check.size(); i++)
                        {
                            if (check[i] == l->destination)
                            {
                                found = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (found == false)
                        {
                            check.push_back(l->destination);
                            q.push(l->destination);
                        }
                    }
                    l = l->next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead, do this to run it for every node.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).